# POSTMAN: paste value at the end of long URL for GET

Tags: postman

Using the standalone Postman app on MacOS, I have a few GET commands with very long URLs.  At the end of a standardized URL, I repeatedly have to paste a value to properly customize the target of the GET command.

I'm thinking there has to be a better way than highlighting the text window, hitting the END button on my keyboard and pasting.

My experiments with entering numbers into the key/value section of PARAMs have been futile.

Anyone?

ex. I'd want to paste a numerical value from the clipboard just after the "/ in orthis/".

https://thissuperlongurlneverchanges.com/neitherdoesthis/orthis/**12345678**

Comment: What were your "futile experiments"? Please have a read through [ask]. Also have you tried the documentation? Was anything not clear? Not working?

Comment: Thanks SiKing.  I was manipulating the Key - Value parameters; which was unsuccessful.

Comment: and yes, I went through all of the documentation before putting forth my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean [Environment Variables](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments)

`DropDown upper right -> Manage Environments -> Edit Evironment`

Type in the `key` input: `myVariable`

Type in the `value` input: `12345678`

Click `Update`

Go back to the `GET` and try:

`https://thissuperlongurlneverchanges.com/neitherdoesthis/orthis/{{myVariable}}`

**NOTE:** If you check the link, you can see that there are some cool options like random integers and stuff like that in the Global Variables section

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are looking for is URL parameters. Change your URL to:

```
https://thissuperlongurlneverchanges.com/neitherdoesthis/orthis/:my_param
```

Then click on "Params" next to the URL. A display similar to the headers display should open up, where you should see one key called "my_param". For the value of this key you can provide anything, like your example "12345678", including an environment variable.

If you actually want query parameters, in this same Params display enter a new key-value. For example, enter "another_param" for the key, and "87654321" for the value. Your URL should now look like:

```
https://thissuperlongurlneverchanges.com/neitherdoesthis/orthis/:my_param?another_param=87654321
```

If you click on the link "Generate Code", you can see the complete resolved request:

```
GET /neitherdoesthis/orthis/12345678?another_param=87654321 HTTP/1.1
Host: thissuperlongurlneverchanges.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ea3be022-2a33-0786-6de4-e5e96b9ce2b6
```

Comment: Thank you @SiKing.  I thought I'd tried that combination.